# RetroPie interruption glitch

Tags: retropie

I installed retropie on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ a month ago. I had no problems since yesterday. When I booted up my raspberry and started playing Super Mario World for the SNES, I noticed that the game randomly got stuck. The music kept playing in the background but the image was paused for about five seconds. This happens about every ten to fifteen seconds.  I looked up at YouTube and also and the retropie forum, but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem. It would be very nice if someone could help me. (This glitch occurred at every console and also at the retro Arch menu)